# Magento 1.9.3 admin panel does not show Configurable swatches

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to configure swatches for sizes in my magento system. Documentation and every single tutorial is showing the same path

System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Configurable Swatches

This is how my catalog options look like:

[image: Magento Admin Panel]

Is it not available with magento 1.9.3 ?
[This](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable-swatch-setup.html)  magento documentation is implying it is available since 1.9.x

Answer (score 0):

swatches in Magento 1.9.3 is available, maybe your account does not have all permission to get there. Your account is Administrator?

Comment: Yes I am a system administrator, I have full access.